# Permalinks with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, permalinks

Is it possible to make a short URL rule so that every word (except the root folders) after http://mydomain.com/ will get redirected to /index.php?permalink=$1 ?

examples:

http://mydomain.com/ - goto index.php (standard). 
http://mydomain.com/word - goto index.php?permalink=word

My .htaccess looks like this right now:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule /page/([0-9]+) /?page=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  RewriteRule ^.*/(\w+)\b$ /index.php?permalink=$1
```

`^` Assert position at the beginning of a line.
`.*/` Match any single character or nothing, until the last `/`.
`(\w+)` Match letters, digits, underscores, at least one char, and capture it as a group number 1.
`\b` Assert position at a word boundary.
`$` Assert position at the end of a line.

Thus:

`http://mydomain.com/word1` **becomes** `/index.php?permalink=word1`
`http://mydomain.com/publish_files/word2` **becomes**  `/index.php?permalink=word2`

For your request on comments, try this, but I haven't tested it yet:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http://)?{HTTP_HOST}/[^/]+/.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http://)?{HTTP_HOST}/\w+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*/(\w+)$ /index.php?permalink=$1
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you please explain your regular expression?

It works, but not quite as I imagined. When I use a word that is not a folder in the root it works. But when I type a word that is a folder I get redircted to http://mydomain.com/publish_files/?permalink=publish_files. I do not understand why it decides to add "?permalink=publish_files" after the URL.

The optimal would be if I could decide in the regex which words should be ignored. Is this possible?

Comment: In your recent case (when you use a word that is a folder), what is your expectation to be? Would you edit your question to include your recent case? I will explain my regex after your problem solved entirely.

Comment: I'm just curious to why it adds "?permalink=word" after the URL if the word is a folder. If its possible to remove this. Otherwise it looks like it works fine. :)

Comment: I have given an explanation of the regex.

Comment: thanks! :) But how do I change it so that http://mydomain.com/word become /index.php?permalink=word and http://mydomain.com/publish_files become /index.php ? :S

Comment: I have edited my answer again. Please try my experimental `RewriteRule`, but I haven't tested it yet. Therefore, please give a feedback whether it works or not.